# info windows for each marker google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I'm having some trouble with implementing some data in the infowindow for dynamic markers that i make with some geopoints from parse.

```
 function initMap(arlat, arlon, arname, artel, ardesc, aradd, arithmisi) {

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                            zoom: 6,
                            center: {
                                lat: 37.58,
                                lng: 23.43
                            }
                        });
                        var iconBase = 'http://sourtouki.gr/';

                        for (j = 0; j < arithmisi; j++) {
                            var contentString = '<div id="content">' +
                                '<div id="siteNotice">' +
                                '</div>' +
                                arname[j] +
                                '<div id="bodyContent">' +
                                ardesc[j] + "<br>" + aradd[j] + "<br>" + artel[j] + "<br>" +
                                '</div>' +
                                '</div>';


                            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: {
                                    lat: arlat[j],
                                    lng: arlon[j]
                                },
                                map: map,
                                icon: iconBase + 'sourtoukilogo.png',        
                                title: arname[j]
                            });        
                        }
                        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                            content: contentString
                        });

                        marker.addListener('click', function() {
                            infowindow.open(map, marker);
                        });
                    }
```

So with the code above i push some data that i have from some tables into the map. The markers are created in the locations as they have to be, but whenever i click on a marker it opens only one.
It loads 17 markers but the only infowindow that opens is the first entry, whatever marker i push.
Also the title of each marker is the correct one.

*UPDATE*
I have 17 entries on this map, 17 geopoints (lat, lng), 17 names, 17description etc.
So with the code above i get all the geoipoints and i put the markers on the correct positions into the map. And i want when i click on a marker to take the name and address and appear it in the infowindow. But i guess i'm somewhere wrong in the for loop. Although i take all the data as they have to be, each geopoint has the correct name etc, but whenever i click a marker, only the 1st entry opens the infowindow, lets say that i click the 3rd marker in the map the 1st infowindow will open, also happens if i push the 12th marker.
Any idea why this happens??

**UPDATE 2**

```
function initMap(arlat, arlon, arname, artel, ardesc, aradd, arithmisi) {



                    // console.log(arlat.length + arlon.lenght);

                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                        zoom: 6,
                        center: {
                            lat: 37.58,
                            lng: 23.43
                        }
                    });
                    var iconBase = 'http://sourtouki.gr/';

                    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                    for (j = 0; j < arithmisi; j++) {

                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: {
                                lat: arlat[j],
                                lng: arlon[j]
                            },
                            map: map,
                            icon: iconBase + 'sourtoukilogo.png',

                            title: arname[j]
                        });
                    var contentString = '<div id="content">' +
                            '<div id="siteNotice">' +
                            '</div>' +
                            arname[j] +
                            '<div id="bodyContent">' +
                            ardesc[j] + "<br>" + aradd[j] + "<br>" + artel[j] + "<br>" +
                            '</div>' +
                            '</div>';

                             google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                                    infowindow.setContent(contentString);
                                    infowindow.open(map,this);

                                 });


                    }


                }
```

On the 2nd update i make an empty infowindow outside the for loop and after i call the content inside and now it opens all the infowindows but it has the same content inside.

Generaly i've tried a lot of answers in other questions here in stackoverflow and none fix worked for my case, if someone could help i would be grateful!

Comment: sorry for not understand enough your problem. what does `It loads 17 markers` mean? Is all data in 17 markers load into one marker in the first entry?

Comment: @HermanNz i will edit my question to explain better

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Maps JS API v3 - Simple Multiple Marker Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example)

Comment: @KwnstantinosNatsios, check first code (not update2) and fix position inside marker: `position: new google.maps.LatLng(arlat[j][1], arlat[j][2]),`

Comment: @HermanNz i get them already as geoipoints from parse.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your for loop is only and not for marker and for infowindow and listener because these are off the loop  try this way .. but most important you need an array of markers instead a single marker this way

```
var markers = [];

for (j = 0; j < arithmisi; j++) {
    var contentString = '<div id="content">' +
        '<div id="siteNotice">' +
        '</div>' +
        arname[j] +
        '<div id="bodyContent">' +
        ardesc[j] + "<br>" + aradd[j] + "<br>" + artel[j] + "<br>" +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>';


    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {
            lat: arlat[j],
            lng: arlon[j]
        },
        map: map,
        icon: iconBase + 'sourtoukilogo.png',        
        title: arname[j]
    });        

    k = markers.push(marker);

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString
    });

    markers[k-1].addListener('click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately click event happens only for the last marker. What is wrong?

Comment: @mdBender  depend .. could be you have not an array of markers ..or you don 't use the clouser (addListener)  in proper way ..then you should post a new question with you code  .. and a clear description of you problem  eventually comment me the link

Answer (score 0):

The content of your infowindow is being set outside of the for loop. So it's always going to be set to the last value of contentString.